# angular showing TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to learn routing by adding routing to a specific page in my rails app using angular which will replace ajax. Below is the console error am getting.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   testApp due to: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

This is how I defined.

**app.js**

```
app = angular.module("testApp", ['ui.router']);

app.config([
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('mylistings', {
                url: '/mylistings',
                templateUrl: '/views/mylistings.html',
                controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
            });
    }
]);

app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
$scope.testing="testdata"
});
```

**mylistings.html**

```
{{testing}}
```

In this case `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` is the url I want routing. Could someone tell me what am doing wrong here.

Comment: no url `/dashboard` shown in config.

Comment: @charlietfl I want it to be something  like http://localhost:3000/dashboard#mylistings...

Comment: http://localhost:3000/dashboard is from my rails app and not by angular. I want routing here because I want a different section  localhost:3000/dashboard#mybookings and some others

Comment: should have a default set using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');` and a state that matches that url. Right now if you go to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` then router doesn't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with definition of config function.
If you use array `app.config([])` that means that you write safe code for the dependencies prepared for minification. Syntax is:

```
app.config(['$arg1', '$arg2', function ($arg1, $arg2) {
   }]);
```

So when code is minified you will get something like:

```
app.config(['$arg1', '$arg2',function(a,b) {}]);
```

In your example in **app.js** change config to following code if you want to write code safe for minification (if you are not using [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)):

```
app = angular.module("testApp", ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('mylistings', {
                url: '/mylistings',
                templateUrl: '/views/mylistings.html',
                controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
            });
    }
]);

app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
  $scope.testing="testdata"
});
```

or you can remove `[]` from config function :

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 ...
}):
```

Comment: Based on the error that he gets '_Cannot read property 'state' of undefined_', that's the problem. Just remove `[]` from config function definition.
Regarding url problem, that's second problem based on configuration, but that is not the question asked about.